# Get Conversations List Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose we have the following structure for the table with the sample data and other users not only 2

[image]

So in this case i should received only one conversation between every two users like

35 to 1 and 
1 to 35

but i tried the below query and i got two conversations

```
select msg_id,msg_from,msg_to,msg_content,msg_status,msg_created_at,
    (select user_name from users where user_id = msg_from ) user_name 
    from messages where msg_id in 
    (select max(msg_id) from messages ) 
    and msg_to = 35 or msg_from = 35
```

Please help in order to get the correct results .

Comment: If you only want 1 conversation, constrain both from and to:  `and ((msg_to = 35 and msg_from = 1) or (msg_to = 1 and msg_from = 35))`  Probably you're getting another party besides user 1 talking to user 35.  You may also be missing a parenthesis `()` set around the `or` terms.

Comment: i don't have only 2 users there are many users :(

Comment: The point is that a) your original query will return anything with `msg_from = 35` due to the `or` with no `()` around it.  b) you need to constrain both ends of the conversation (1 and 35) not just one of them (35).

Comment: @ebyrob Thanks u r right, i forget the parenthesis .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put the condition `msg_to = 35 or msg_from = 35` between parentheses and move it inside the sub query returning the max id. as in the code below:

```
select msg_id,msg_from,msg_to,msg_content,msg_status,msg_created_at,
(select user_name from users where user_id = msg_from ) user_name 
from messages where msg_id in 
(select max(msg_id) from messages  
where (msg_to = 35 or msg_from = 35))
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the parenthesis around the `or` statements:

```
select msg_id,msg_from,msg_to,msg_content,msg_status,msg_created_at,
    (select user_name from users where user_id = msg_from ) user_name 
from messages where msg_id in 
    (select max(msg_id) from messages ) 
    and (msg_to = 35 or msg_from = 35)
```